# convert audio file to base64 in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to save an audio and send it to the server in ionic 3.

```
record(){
  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.fileName = 'record'+new Date().getDate()+new Date().getMonth()+new 
    Date().getFullYear()+new Date().getHours()+new Date().getMinutes()+new 
    Date().getSeconds()+'.3gp';
    this.filePath = this.file.documentsDirectory.replace(/file:\/\//g, '') + 
    this.fileName;
    this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
  } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
    this.fileName = 'record'+new Date().getDate()+new Date().getMonth()+new 
    Date().getFullYear()+new Date().getHours()+new Date().getMinutes()+new 
    Date().getSeconds()+'.3gp';
    this.filePath = this.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(/file:\/\//g, '') 
    + this.fileName;
    this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
  }
    this.audio.startRecord();
    this.recording = true;
}
```

After stopping the record i want to send the audio file in base64 to the server. so I am using the base64 plugin to convert the audio file to base64.

```
this.base64.encodeFile(this.filePath).then((base64File: string) => {
            // let audiooo = encodeURIComponent(base64File);
            this.sendVoice(encodeURIComponent(base64File));
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

However, using this plugin i get base64File with the below value:

```
data%3Aimage%2F%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%3Bbase64%2C%2f%2FFsQBIF%2FAFAC....

I cannot play this encoded audio after sending it to the server, i believe it is because the file starts data%3Aimage... not with data%3Aaudio...
```

So any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: your work is nice! check the answer I tried the algorithm there by native lib it did not work for me but I changed the track and used this plugin that I showed down below!

Answer (score 1):

Use my answer in this post. It is an official library. [Ionic 3 get base64 audio string from recorded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966852/ionic-3-get-base64-audio-string-from-recorded-file/54942909#54942909)

To add the plugin in your project:

1. Use:`ionic cordova plugin add com-badrit-base64` to add the
   pluggin.
2. Use:`npm install @ionic-native/base64` to add the module
   in your proyect and your package.json
3. Import in your `module.ts` importing the libary like:`import { Base64 } from "@ionic-native/base64";`
4. Add it in the providers JSON.

   ```
   providers:[
         Camera,
         Media,
         File,
         SpeechRecognition,
         Base64,
   ],
   ```
5. Declare this new library in constructor of your component:`private base64:Base64,`
6. Use the method.

   ```
   this.base64.encodeFile(this.filePath + this.fileName).then(
   (base64:any) =>{
     console.log('file base64 encoding: ' + base64);
     var x = base64.substr(13,base64.length);
     x = "data:audio/mpeg;base64" + x;
   });
   ```

Comment: Just change the import to import { Base64 } from "@ionic-native/base64/ngx"

Comment: @CarlosMontiel ngx is for ionic 4 and answer is correct for ionic 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

I have different solution for this! as the basic native bas64 was not working properly

**Solution**

I have this amazing **[library](https://github.com/jimmylagp/Base64-Encode-Decode-Audio)** that I used before to do audio conversion to base 64
   //Encode Audio MP3 to Base64
    var pathToFile = "/pathToFile/audio.mp3";

```
Base64ToAudio.readAudio(pathToFile, 
    function(sourceAudio)
    {
        console.log(sourceAudio) //Return Base64 String
    },
    function(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
);

//Decode Audio MP3 from Base64 and save file on storage.
var conf = { "b64string": sourceAudio, "filename": "new-voice.mp3", "folder": "/pathToDirectory/", "overwrite": true };

Base64ToAudio.saveAudio(conf,
    function(success){
        console.log(success); //Return OK when the file is generated.
    },
    function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Comment: thank you for your post. But can you explain how to integrate this lib in with my ionic project??

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL):

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = () => {
  let base64 = reader.result // Here is your base64.
}
```

Comment: thanks. But do you have any idea how to convert mediaObject to a blob or file type??

Comment: Sorry I assumed you had a file object, so the audio and file objects in your code are just file paths?

Comment: the audio is of type mediaObject and i have its path(filepath)

Comment: Did you try creating a `File` object first using the path in the constructor and then using this object in the `reader.readAsDataURL()` call above? E.g. `new File("/path/to/file");`