# Convert audio(type mediaObject) to base64 in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 framework and i want to convert an audio of type mediaObject to base 64 and then send it to the server. I want to use this plugin:

```
https://github.com/jimmylagp/Base64-Encode-Decode-Audio
```

I need help to integrate this plugin in my project. I tried npm install and then tried to put the files in my project but got none works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my post on [Ionic 3 get base64 audio string from recorded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966852/ionic-3-get-base64-audio-string-from-recorded-file/52000679#52000679)

By using the **readAsDataURL** function, it is able to convert the audio file to base64 format